# Limit of $\sinh z$ as $z\to i$.

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I'm trying to understand why

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow\ i} \sinh(z)= i\sin(1)$$

Thanks for any feedback.
I tried using $\sinh(z)=(e^{z}-e^{-z})/2$ but that only seemed to make things more complicated now I'm thinking that L'Hopital may be needed but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be helpful to recall that:

$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ thus:

$e^i = e^{i1} = \cos(1) + i\sin(1)$.

Comment: thank you so much your hint helped me a lot and i was finally able to see how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
\sin (z)&=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
i\sin (1)&=\frac{e^{i}-e^{-i}}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Plugging it into that formula is exactly the way to do it. Try looking carefully at $$\sinh(i)=\frac{e^{i}-e^{-i}}{2}$$ and then at $$i\sin(1)=i\frac{e^{1i}-e^{-1i}}{2i}$$ and see if you can see why they are the same...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Answer (score -2):

Recall the identity $\sinh(iz)=i\sin z$. Then
$$
\lim_{z \to i} \sinh(z)=\sinh i=\sinh(i\cdot 1)=i \sin(1)
$$

Comment: "Proof by knowing the general case to be true" is usually not a very helpful answer

Comment: @StellaBiderman It depends on what they are assumed to know in the course. I do not know what the OP does/does not know. In my introductory Complex Analysis text, this equality was introduced within 3 lines of the definition of complex sinh.